# how to add a generated resource to resource path in gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a custom Gradle Java task in which I am generating a json file. I would like to add this generated file to the list of project resources so that it is bundled with the jar file when packaging is happening and I would like to do this inside the task itself. I tried the following code but I got an error saying I can not modify resources collection in main source set. Is there any other way to do this?

```
mainSourceSet.getResources().add(new SimpleFileCollection(generatedResources));
```